# Need to scrape a table which is loaded through ajax using python(selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a [page](https://seahawks.strmarketplace.com/Charter-Seat-Licenses/Charter-Seat-Licenses.aspx) that has a table (table id= "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_ctl00_GV" class="GridListings" )i need to scrape.
I usually use BeautifulSoup  & urllib for it,but in this case the problem is that the table takes some time to load ,so it isnt captured when i try to fetch it using BS.
I cannot use PyQt4,drysracpe or windmill because of some installation issues,so the only possible way is to use Selenium/PhantomJS
I tried the following,still no success:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_ctl00_GV'))
```

The above code doesnt give me the desired contents of the table.
How do i go about achieveing this???

Comment: What do you mean doesnt give me the desired contents?? Is there any exception?? And Could you share your table HTML here as well??

Comment: Hi,[link](https://seahawks.strmarketplace.com/Charter-Seat-Licenses/Charter-Seat-Licenses.aspx) the bottom table is what i want(table  with class="GridListings")

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not able to view table this time that's why I'm telling you share here the table HTML..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the data using *requests* and *bs4,*, with almost if not all asp sites there are a few post params that always need to be provided like *__EVENTTARGET*, *__EVENTVALIDATION* etc.. :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = {"__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$ctl00$RadAjaxPanel_GV",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": "LISTINGS;0",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$hdnProductID": "139",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$ctl00$hdnProductID": "139",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$ctl00$drpSortField": "Listing Number",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$ctl00$drpSortDirection": "A-Z, Low-High",
    "__ASYNCPOST": "true"}
```

And for the actual post, we need to add a few more values to out post data:

```
post = "https://seahawks.strmarketplace.com/Charter-Seat-Licenses/Charter-Seat-Licenses.aspx"
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update({"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(post).content)

    data["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"]
    data["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]
    data["__VIEWSTATE"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"]

    r = s.post(post, data=data)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    table = soup2.select_one("div.GridListings")
    print(table)
```

You will see the table printed when you run the code.

Comment: You are absolutely right!!!!! Ican see the table now.Thanks a lot!!!I have a doubt though,since we are statically posting few params to the page,there is no chance of the same page being downloaded right?I mean the table is going to be the updated one every time we run this right?

Comment: @user3425403, yes, we are only really doing the required validation, there are also lot more params you can pass, I have not looked through them all but you should be able to influence how the data is returned by adding more.

Comment: ,is there a way to identify which are the required form data's?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scrap something, it will be nice first to install a web debugger ( [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) for example) to watch how the website you want to scrap is working.

Next, you need to copy the process of how the website is connecting to backoffice

As you said, the content that you want to scrap is being loaded asynchronously (only when the document is ready)

Assuming the debugger is running and also you have refreshed the page, you will see on the network tab the following request:

POST https://seahawks.strmarketplace.com/Charter-Seat-Licenses/Charter-Seat-Licenses.aspx

The final process flow to reach your goal will be:

- 1/ Use [requests python module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)
- 2/ Open a requests session to the index page website site (with cookies handling)
- 3/ Scrap all the input for the specific POST form request
- 4/ Build a POST parameter DICT containing all inputs & value fields scrapped in the previous step + adding some specific fixed params.
- 5/ POST the request (with required data)
- 6/ Use finally [BS4 module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2) (as usual) to soup the answered html to scrap your data

Please see bellow a working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url="https://seahawks.strmarketplace.com/Charter-Seat-Licenses/Charter-Seat-Licenses.aspx"

#create requests session
s = requests.session()

#get index page
r=s.get(base_url)

#soup page
bs=BeautifulSoup(r.text)

#extract FORM html
form_soup= bs.find('form',{'name':'aspnetForm'})

#extracting all inputs
input_div = form_soup.findAll("input")

#build the data parameters for POST request
#we add some required <fixed> data parameters for post
data={
    '__EVENTARGUMENT':'LISTINGS;0',
    '__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$ctl00$RadAjaxPanel_GV',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION':'/wEWGwKis6fzCQLDnJnSDwLq4+CbDwK9jryHBQLrmcucCgL56enHAwLRrPHhCgKDk6P+CwL1/aWtDQLm0q+gCALRvI2QDAKch7HjBAKWqJHWBAKil5XsDQK58IbPAwLO3dKwCwL6uJOtBgLYnd3qBgKyp7zmBAKQyTBQK9qYAXAoieq54JAuG/rDkC1djKyQMC1qnUtgoC0OjaygUCv4b7sAhfkEODRvsa3noPfz2kMsxhAwlX3Q=='
}
#we add some <dynamic> data parameters
for input_d in input_div:
    try:
        data[ input_d['name'] ] =input_d['value'] 
    except:
        pass #skip unused input field

#post request
r2=s.post(base_url,data=data)

#write the result
with open("post_result.html","w") as f:
    f.write(r2.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Now, please get a look at "post_result.html" content and you will find the data !

Regards

Comment: Did u check the post paramaters to the page??I dont think thats gonna work.You will understand if u had looked at the post request

Comment: Year, that is why I added step 3 & 4 in the process, I will update my answer with a working code in the next 5 min.

Comment: Thanks for the effort,but still that table is not captured : look at the output file,the table would come up inside the innerdiv below,which is still empty <div class="GridListings">
    <div>

                        </div>
    </div>

Comment: Yes, you are right that the table div is empty :-) But there is more data visible in the document (we can see the section for example). We maybe need to add fixed headers an/or some data params to the POST request

Comment: Code was updated : adding __EVENTARGUMENT, __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTVALIDATION are required data params

Comment: @padraic-cunningham:  Please do not try again to predict who copy/paste parts of a working answer ... Because you fail in your prediction, then it is not smart at all and to conclude your comment is unacceptable (from my point of view). Regards

Comment: @padraic-cunningham: I confirm you the multiple edit, you are right on that point but let me expect a mispredict when you said "Don 't blindly copy part of another answer" because I didn't do it ! SO I don't care finally but it s definitly not cool for helper (or people who try to help) ...