# When trying to log in using requests module, I get an error because the User/Password fields are blank

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to make a scraper to get my grades from my schools website. Unfortunately i cannot log in. When i try to run the program, the return page validates the user/password fields, and since they are blank, it's not letting me proceed.

Also, i am not really sure if I am even coding this correctly.

```
from twill.commands import *
import requests

payload = {
'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgn$UserName':'user',
'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgn$Password':'pass',
}

cookie = {
'En_oneTime_ga_tracking_v2' : 'true',
'ASP.NET_SessionId' : ''
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('schoolUrl', data=payload, cookies=cookie)
    print p.text
```

---

Updated payload:

```
payload = {
    'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$UserName':'user',
    'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$Password':'pass',
    '__LASTFOCUS': '',
    '__EVENTTARGET':'',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
    '__VIEWSTATE':  'LONG NUMBER',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'C2EE9ABB',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' : 'LONG NUMBER',
    'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$RememberMe': 'on',
    'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$LoginButton':'Log+In' 
}
```

How do i know if my POST was successful?

The returned page was saying that Username/Password cannot be blank.

---

Complete source:

```
from twill.commands import *
import requests
payload = {
    'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$UserName':'user',
    'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$Password':'pass',
    '__LASTFOCUS': '',
    '__EVENTTARGET':'',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
    '__VIEWSTATE':  'LONG NUMBER',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'C2EE9ABB',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' : 'LONG NUMBER',
    'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$RememberMe': 'on',
    'ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$LoginButton':'Log In' 
}

 cookie = {
    'En_oneTime_ga_tracking_v2' : 'true',
    'ASP.NET_SessionId' : ''
 }

with requests.Session() as s:

    loginUrl = 'http://eaglesnest.pcci.edu/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f'
    gradeUrl = 'http://eaglesnest.pcci.edu/StudentServices/ClassGrades/Default.aspx'
    p = s.post( loginUrl, data=payload)
    print p.text
```

Comment: Please post your full code, I do not get the same error but an error that the username/password combination is wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773397/need-to-scrap-a-table-which-is-loaded-through-ajax-using-pythonselenium/38775553#38775553 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724326/making-subsequent-post-request-in-session-doesnt-work-web-scraping/36725215#36725215

Answer (score 0):

Your payload uses the wrong keys, try

```
ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$UserName
ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$Password
```

You can check the names by watching the network traffic in your browser (e.g. in Firefox: inspect element --> network --> post --> params)

In addition you need to specify which command you want to perform, i.e. which button was pressed.

```
payload['ctl00$cphMainContent$lgnEaglesNest$LoginButton': 'Log In']
```

Comment: Yea i deleted that part because of privacy, then forgot to delete the url. lol

But you are right, those are the keys i currently use.

Comment: Did you try it again with the correct keys for username/password/button?

Comment: I just added the complete source

Comment: I also tried to the run the program, and i got "username /password is required"

Comment: That's the standard JavaScript which is always shown, you need to look for:   Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.

Comment: Yea i am not getting that. Is it because my POST data isn't being sent successfully?